# How to redirect on login page in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, next.js

I want to open login page, when user is not logged in. But first opens the page `index.js` and only then sends it to the page `login.js`.

My code

```
export default function redirectTo(destination, { res, status } = {}) {
    if (res) {
        res.writeHead(status || 302, { Location: destination })
        res.end()
    } else {
        if (destination[0] === '/' && destination[1] !== '/') {
            Router.push(destination)
        } else {
            window.location = destination
        }
    }
}
```

And in `_app.js`

```
const {token} = useAuth()

useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
         redirectTo('/login', {})
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: In the [useRouter documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage) there is a redirect example.

Comment: there is example for redirect from one page to another, but i want open the site in login.js when user is not loggined, before open the index.js

Comment: I think you would need to implement a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) for that.

Comment: where i must to call function getServerSideProps? In _app,js? 
const {token} = useAuth()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token){
      getServerSideProps()
    }
  }, [token])

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake :

```
Router.push(destination) ==> destination as a string does not do the job
```

Change it to:

```
Router.push({ pathname: destination })
```